# Microsoft Azure: How to use Multi-Factor (Four-Eye) Authorization

Tags: security, azure

I was wondering if it possible to have some kind of workflow for managing resources in Microsoft Azure. My goal is to have two persons having to agree on certain actions in Resource Manager. I want to prevent a single person being able to delete resources or resource groups without a second person having approved the change.

Is it possible to have something like this in Azure?

Best regards, Sebastian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to prevent a single person being able to delete resources or
>   resource groups without a second person having approved the change.

As of today, it is not possible in Azure. If someone has permission to delete a resource, they can delete that resource without any approval workflow. It may be helpful to ask for this feature by providing feedback to Azure team here http://feedback.azure.com.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.